# euclidean distance to a "curved" structure

Tags: matlab, geometry, computational-geometry

I have written a program that works with the Euclidean distance of a current resource to the surface of a geometric figure.
In our geometric considerations the y-coordinate is always zero - so it is a 2D structure in x and z dimension.
The figure shows how it looks:

[image: picture 1]

(length yellow = 100 , length blue = 500) -- so if for example the origin is in the middle of the second yellow section, the point source is then for example at a coordinate of coord=(700,0,510) and one can of course for each midpoint of a blue or yellow section the Euclidean distance by means of:

sqrt(sum(((midpoints-coord))^2)

but how can I do this if I "bend" this "stick" by say an angle $\alpha$ from a certain section?:

[image: pic2]

the y-coordinate is again zero and the source is again placed vertically in the z-direction - but how do I then determine the Euclidean distance to the centers of the sections?
so we use the same length dimensions, only we bend the stick by 30% in the direction of the electrode, for example at the origin or at the 5 segment.The best way would be to manipulate the "x" value of the midpoints accordingly....

Comment: Are you looking for a way to compute the position of the midpoints of your "bended" segments? Or do you have them?

Comment: @PatrickHappel yes i want to compute them - because then i can simply take the eucl. distance

Comment: If I understand your question, it has in fact nothing to do with the Euclidean distances. You are just asking how to find the centers of the sections, right ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes exactly

Comment: Then I don't understand why you accepted @omg's answer, which does not address that at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it was a miss-click

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you have another suggestion besides Futurologists ?

Comment: @Math_Man1: what is wrong with his solution ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust absolutely nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Just you can do the same by a binary search and find the closest point on the curve (through midpoints) to the given point.

Also, if you have the closed-form of the curve, denoted by `z = f(x)`, and a given point `(x_1, 0, z_1)`, you can solve the following optimization problem:

```
argmin_{x} (x_1 - x)^2 + (z_1 - f(x))^2
```

The solution of the above optimization task is the nearest point of the curve to the given point.

To solve the optimization task, you can use different methods depending on the closed-form of `f`.

If you are using python, you can find many useful libraries for the optimization task, respectively.

Comment: Dear OmG! thank you for your answer, but i am looking for the distance to the mid points. The closed form of the "classical stick" would be an array of midpoints lets say midpoints(x) = (-1000,....,0,.....1000,...2000) and coord=(700,0,510) then i can calculate the distance to the midpoints. But now i want to "bend" the stick for example at 0 in an angle of 50 degree -- then on the right hand side the x-values are still (0,....1000,...2000) but on the lefthandside they get "closer" to the electrode and i want to calculate now the new midpoints and the eucl. distance to it

Comment: @Math_Man1 My pleasure. As I've explained, you can do a binary search to find the closest midpoints to the given point.

Comment: but i dont know what you mean by a closed form of z=f(x), since f would just be an array of point

Comment: @Math_Man1 So, you can ignore the second part. It's just explained for completeness of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to Matlab right now, so I wrote some code in python. Is this what you want to do?:

```py
# plotting function of a polyline, a point and, if chosen, midpoints of polyline
def plot_polyline(P, P0, equal_axes, show_midpoints):
    M = midpoints_of(P)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(P0[0], P0[1], 'bo')
    plt.plot(P[:,0], P[:,1])
    for k in range(P.shape[0]):
        plt.plot(P[k,0], P[k,1], 'ro')
    if show_midpoints:
        for k in range(M.shape[0]):
            plt.plot(M[k,0], M[k,1], 'yo')
    axx = plt.gca()
    if equal_axes:
        axx.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()
    return None

def cos_sin(angle):
    return  math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)

# generate a rotation matrix that rotates a 2D vector at an angle alpha
# observe the matrix format is [x1, y1] = [x, y].dot([[cos, -sin],
#                                                     [sin, cos]])
# and rotation is clockwise rotation of vector written as row-vectors 
def rot_matrx(angle):
    cs, sn = cos_sin(angle)
    return np.array([[  cs, -sn], 
                     [  sn,  cs]]) 

# performs a clockwise rotation of a point around a center at an angle 
def rotate(points, angle, center):
    U = rot_matrx(angle)
    return (points - center).dot(U) + center
 
# bending
def perform_bending(polyline, angle, index_bending_point):    
    x1 = polyline.copy()  
    x_bend  = x1[index_bending_point,:]
    # rotate half angle around point x_bend first         
    x1[0:index_bending_point,:] = rotate(x1[0:index_bending_point,:], 
                                               angle/2, x_bend) 
    # rotate the result from above half angle more around point x_(bend-1)   
    x_bend = x1[(index_bending_point-1),:]
    x1[0:(index_bending_point - 1),:] = rotate(x1[0:(index_bending_point - 1),:], 
                                                   angle/2, x_bend)      
    return x1

# calculate the array of midpoints of the polyline
def midpoints_of(polyline):
    k, m = polyline.shape
    return (polyline[0:(k-1), :] + polyline[1:k, :]) / 2

# calculate the distances from point to the midpoints of a polyline
def calc_distances(point, mids_of_polyline):
    return np.linalg.norm(point-mids_of_polyline, axis=1)


   
# initialize example:   
a = 2 # yellow segments' lenght
b = 5 # blue segments' lenght
n = 12 # number of segments + 1, number of points separating segments

alpha = 40  # angle of bending in degrees
alpha = math.pi * 40/180 # angle in bending in radians

# generate [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
I = np.arange(0,n)

# generate the x[0,] and x[1,] coordinates of the polygonal line
x = np.empty((n, 2), dtype=float)
I = np.floor(I / 2)*(a+b) + (I % 2)*a
x[:, 0] = I.T
x[:, 1] = 0

# point on x that is coordinate origin
x0 = (x[2,:] + x[3,:])/2
# shift initial polyline:
x = x - x0

# index of bending point
i_bend=5

x_bent = perform_bending(x, angle=alpha, index_bending_point=i_bend) 
x_mids = midpoints_of(x_bent)

# point
p = np.array([x_mids[i_bend-1, 0], 5.1])
    
dist = calc_distances(p, x_mids)

plot_polyline(x, p, equal_axes=True, show_midpoints=False)
plot_polyline(x_bent, p, equal_axes=True, show_midpoints=True)
plot_polyline(x_bent, p, equal_axes=True, show_midpoints=False)

print(dist)
```